# Plotting latitudes and longitudes in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
sns.jointplot(x="latitude",y="longitude",data=prop_df,size=7)
plt.ylabel('longitude')
plt.xlabel('latitude')
plt.show()
```

here the latitudes are plotted on the x-axis and longitudes are plotted on the y-axis and its giving the correct plot . This Data is from the Kaggle Zillow dataset[image: plotted based on the data from the zillow prize challenge]

shouldn't the  latitudes be on the y-axis(horizontal lines) and longitudes be in the x-axis(vertical lines)
which is kind of obvious from the way they are defined. 
what is the reason for this difference?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the exact problem but in the code from the question you ask for the
`"latitude"` column along x and the `"longitude"` column along y:

```
sns.jointplot(x="latitude",y="longitude", data=prop_df)
```

If you want the `"latitude"` column along y and the `"longitude"` column along x you could reverse them in the call to `jointplot`:

```
sns.jointplot(x="longitude",y="latitude", data=prop_df)
```

Apart from that the result will of course depend on whether the "longitude" column indeed contains longitudes as values, which cannot be verified without the original data.

Comment: i'm getting the right graph taking latitude as the x axis and longitude as y axis . It's the  data related to houses in california you can faintly notice the shape in the plot. when I take the opposite like you mentioned it's outputting a wrong plot. i want to know why this is happening? since intuitively latitude values are taken on the y axis and longitude on the x axis

Comment: Can you please link to the **exact** data?! I did find some data on kaggle which looked related but does not have any latitude or longitude columns in it.

Comment: https://www.kaggle.com/c/zillow-prize-1/data , properties_2016.csv file

Comment: The page asks me to put my phone number in; which is not acceptable. Sorry.